# Calling a function as part of re.sub in Python "eval equivalent in perl"

Tags: python, perl, eval

I need to be able to call a function in a pattern matching statement with the matched patterned as argument and use the return result of the function as replacement for the matched pattern.  In perl, one can use **eval** function to do that.  Here is the perl example:

`test =~ s/(>?,)(\d+)/eval q{&sum($1,$2)}/ge;`

How can I do this in Python.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's parallel to Perl's `eval EXPR` is also named [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

To be more specific,

```perl
eval( $code )
```

is equivalent to

```py
DOLLAR_AT = None      # Global var $@

def perl_eval( code ):
   try:
      DOLLAR_AT = None
      return eval( code )
   catch BaseException as err:
      DOLLAR_AT = err

perl_eval( code )
```

---

But you're actually asking about the parallel of `/e`. This is what allows the replacement expression to be a Perl expression. In Python, similar results can be achieved by passing a function for `re.sub`'s second parameter.

```perl
$test =~ s/(\d+)\+(\d+)/ $1 + $2 /eg;
```

is equivalent to

```py
test = re.sub( r"(\d+)\+(\d+)", lambda _: str( int( _.group(1) ) + int( _.group(2) ) ), test )
```

---

Now, let's look at the code you posted. We don't care about `$@` here, so the Python equivalent of

```perl
$test =~ s/(>?,)(\d+)/ eval q{sum( $1, $2 )} /ge;
```

is

```py
import re

def replacer( match ):
   try:
      return eval( "sum(" + match.group(1) + ", " + match.group(2) + ")" )
   except:
      return None

test = re.sub( r"(>?,)(\d+)", replacer, test )
```

[Missing: The Perl snippet warns when the replacement expression returns `None`.]

---

That said, this use of `eval` is completely wrong.

Because `sum(>,123)` is not valid Perl, the Perl snippet is equivalent to

```perl
$test =~ s/(>)?,(\d+)/ defined( $1 ) ? undef : eval { sum( $2 ) } /ge;
```

or

```py
import re

def replacer( match ):
   if match.group(1) is None:
      return None
   else
      try:
         return sum( match.group(2) )
      except:
         return None

test = re.sub( r"(>)?,(\d+)", replacer, test )
```

[Missing: The Perl snippet warns when the replacement expression returns `None`.]

[Python's parallel to `eval BLOCK` is `try`.]

This makes absolutely no sense. The following is probably closer to the author's intentions:

```perl
$test =~ s/(>?,)(\d+)/ sum( $1, $2 ) /ge;
```

or

```py
import re
  
test = re.sub( r"(>?,)(\d+)", lambda _ : sum( _.group(1), _.group(2) ), test )
```

---

That might not be it. Passing `>,` or `,` to a sub named `sum` doesn't seem right. But without knowing what `sum` does and what the snippet is supposed to do, I can't comment further.

Comment: This kind of answers is the reason SO still shines (+1).

Comment: Thank you so much, I learned a lot from your explanation and examples.  Do appreciate it